# Why are there some errors of undefined names in flutter? I also encountered other problems as follows

Tags: flutter, undefined

Here is my code:
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RandomWords(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return Text(wordPair.asPascalCase);
  }
}
class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RandomWordsState createState() => _RandomWordsState();
  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd) return const Divider(); /*2*/

          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
          }
          return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }
}
```

My error messages:
Undefined name '_biggerFont'.
Undefined name '_suggestions'.
Undefined name '_suggestions'.
Undefined name '_suggestions'.
The value of the local variable 'wordPair' isn't used.
The declaration '_buildSuggestions' isn't referenced.

Thank you very much for your help.

I rewrote the code for creating an infinite scrolling listview:
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that
can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Startup Name Generator',
        home: RandomWords(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RandomWords(),
        ),
      );
    )
  }
}

class _RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Startup Name Generator'),
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0);

  _RandomWordsState createState() => _RandomWordsState();

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd) return const Divider();
          /*2*/
          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
          }
          return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }
}
```

More errors came: The method 'RandomWords' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.The named parameter 'appBar' isn't defined.The named parameter 'body' isn't defined.The method 'RandomWords' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.Expected an identifier.Expected to find ';'.'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound 'StatefulWidget' of the type parameter 'T'.....
Where am I wrong? I am always confused about ), ); and }. Can you tell me where I use which one of them and where I can read more about code rules?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define _suggestions and _biggerFont in the class RandomWords since you use it there.
If you want to use it in the State as well you can access it via widget._suggestions and widget._biggerFont.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I changed a little bit to create an infinite scrolling ListView, but more errors came up, and some of them are about ), ); or }. I wonder when I can use each of them.